# after unlock a NSRecursiveLock at one queue, other queue still waiting

Tags: ios, locking

I have some code not thread safe, So I tried to use NSRecursiveLock to prevent my work queue and  main thread access some properties at the same time. I create two work queue(work queue and wait queue), work queue to do some heavy work. In order to prevent block main thread, I create another wait queue to wait the lock, so I can async to main thread after I get the lock.

I face two problem:

1. after the work queue unlock, wait queue still waiting.
2. code will get two kind of output

I think the output should be

```
1. work queue get lock
2. wait queue wait lock
3. post notification from work queue
noti called
unlock
get lock
4. main thread do work
```

but I get Output:

```
[Output 1]
1. work queue get lock
2. wait queue wait lock
3. post notification from work queue
noti called
unlock

[Output 2]
1. work queue get lock
2. wait queue wait lock
get lock
4. main thread do work
3. post notification from work queue
noti called
unlock
```

[image]

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) NSLock *lock;
@property (nonatomic) NSRecursiveLock *recursiveLock;
@property (nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t queue;
@property (nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t lockWaitQueue;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _queue = dispatch_queue_create("serial", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    _lockWaitQueue = dispatch_queue_create("wait_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"noti" object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
        NSLog(@"noti called");
    }];
    _lock = [NSLock new];
    _recursiveLock = [NSRecursiveLock new];
    [self tryFixDeadLockCace];
}

- (void)tryFixDeadLockCace {
    NSRecursiveLock *lock = _recursiveLock;
    dispatch_queue_t queue = _queue;
    dispatch_queue_t lockWaitQueue = _lockWaitQueue;
    NSLog(@"1. work queue get lock");
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        [lock lock];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            dispatch_async(lockWaitQueue, ^{
                NSLog(@"2. wait queue wait lock");
                [lock lock];
                NSLog(@"get lock");
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSLog(@"4. main thread do work");
                    [lock unlock];
                });
            });
        });
    });
    
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), queue, ^{
        NSLog(@"3. post notification from work queue");
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"noti" object:nil];
        NSLog(@"unlock");
        [lock unlock];
    });
}

- (void)noti {
    
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

if user NSRecursiveLock, should not use GCD, because lock an unlock may not on the same thread
[image]